# Looking for help on how to use the new denoising data

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

Recently in Blender 2.8 and 2.79 Master a new set of render passes have been made available to the user, "Denoising Data". I have a few questions: How would someone use this information? and is it possible to use this to denoise one pass such as the Indirect Glossy pass?

Thanks in advanced - Alaska

Answer (score 1):

I asked over on the devtalk site and recieved this answer from Brecht Lommel:

> It’s intended for the upcoming feature of animation denoising, where denoising happens in a post processing pass ones all the frames have been rendered. It doesn’t really have a purpose outside of that.

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-can-the-new-denoising-data-be-used/3071